# Sql Query To Sum Amount Before the Date And After Between Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a SQL query to sum the amount before the date and after between dates.

I have the following table in my database. Now what I want to find out is the total sum (DebitAmount) - Sum (CreditAmount) that is before 2021 and then from 2021-01-01 to 2021-03-01:

Table Script

```
CREATE TABLE [Ledger](
    [BaseLedgerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SaveDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_BaseLedger_SaveDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [Account] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DebitAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_BaseLedger_DebitAmount]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CreditAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_BaseLedger_CreditAmount]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BaseLedger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BaseLedgerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]




INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2019-01-01','Sale',500,0)
INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2019-02-01','Sale',600,0)
INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2019-03-01','Sale',800,0)

INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2020-01-01','Sale',1200,0)
INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2020-02-01','Sale',200,0)
INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2020-03-01','Sale',300,0)

INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2021-01-01','Sale',2000,0)
INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2021-02-01','Sale',2500,0)
INSERT Ledger (  [SaveDate],[Account], [DebitAmount], [CreditAmount]) VALUES ('2021-03-01','Sale',450,0)
```

The Query I Have tried

```
-------------Previous Years
SELECT        Account, SUM(DebitAmount) - SUM(CreditAmount) AS Amount
FROM            Ledger WHERE CAST(SaveDate AS Date) < '2021-01-01'
Group by Account

Union

---------Curent Year
SELECT        Account, SUM(DebitAmount) - SUM(CreditAmount) AS Amount
FROM            Ledger WHERE CAST(SaveDate AS Date) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-03-01'
Group by Account
```

The Result is in two row but i want to be sum in one row and if possible to do not use Union

```
+---------+---------+
| Account | Amount  |
+---------+---------+
| Sale    | 3600.00 |
| Sale    | 4950.00 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: can you the data in the form of insert scripts ? Also, share the expected result from the sample database.

Comment: I have tried to Add A table But its Show code not the result

Comment: please add your script, from data and your tried query

Comment: Please show what you have tried. And don't use images to display data.

Comment: Do you want the total overall or per account?  If you want the overall total, why are you aggregating by account?

Comment: `[Account] [nvarchar](max) NULL,` HIGHLY doubtful this is an appropriate datatype. Every column nullable is also a bad sign and a huge problem. Fix your schema NOW. Typically one records a DATE for a transaction (not a datetime) - another bad smell.

Comment: And learn the significant difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. Had those sums for the Sale account been the same for the two periods, your resultset would have contained a single row - something you might not have noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the value in two separate columns.  If you want the result by account:

```
SELECT Account,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN SaveDate < '2021-01-01' THEN DebitAmount ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN SaveDate < '2021-01-01' THEN CreditAmount ELSE 0 END)
      ) AS Amount_Before,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN SaveDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-03-01' THEN DebitAmount ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN SaveDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-03-01' THEN CreditAmount ELSE 0 END)
      ) AS Amount_After
FROM Ledger 
GROUP BY Account;
```

If you want totals, then remove `Account` from the `SELECT` and remove the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUM(Total)
FROM
  Sales
 WHERE [Date] < '2021-01-01'
 UNION
SELECT
  SUM(Total)
FROM
  Sales
 WHERE [Date] > '2020-12-31' AND [Date] < '2021-03-01'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0cdc/3)